# Multi tenancy in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

Yet another multi tenancy post im afraid.
I just cant find a good solution to my problem, I have read all the great posts on multi tenancy for ASP MVC but I still need some good advice.

Im going to create a corporate presence for one of my customers. Their company structure is like a main company (ex. Acme Group Ltd.) which own several other companies (ex. Acme Holding Ltd, Acme Technology Ltd., Acme Maritime Ltd., etc.).

I want to use one ASP MVC project to serve as the container for all the sites to cut down on the code needed and to keep it DRY. I also want all the sites to use the same Membership DB.

My first thought was to make one controller folder for each sub-company and one root controller for the corporate main page. Then it would look like:

> acme.com ("Corporate main page")
>   acme.com/Holding ("Acme Holding Ltd.")
>   acme.com/Maritme ("Acme Maritme Ltd.")
>   ...

This structure is fine by me, but I also want the users of the website to access each sub-site based on their own separate domains, ex:

> holding.acme.com (This should direct to "acme.com/Holding").
>   ...

That would of course also work, but the thing is that I do not want the url to change when the user is directed to "acme.com/Holding". I would like it to still be "holding.acme.com", "holding.acme.com/About", "holding.acme.com/Contact", etc. instead of "acme.com/Holding/Contact", etc.

What would be the best practice to use in this particular project, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have access to MVC2? And have you looked at the 'areas' feature in it?

Comment: Actually, im using MVC2 but I have not looked at areas. I'll take a look now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep it simple, use IIS [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/expand/URLRewrite). You can set it up to rewrite  `acme-holding.com/*` URLs to `acme.com/Holding/*`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Forward to acme.com">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://acme.com/Holding/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I guess i'll go with this combined with DaRKoN_s tip regarding the "areas" in MVC2. Im just wondering if this would be the best practice or should I handle it differently?

Comment: I believe the best practice would be to redirect instead of rewriting. Google doesn't like the same content with different URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog on multi-tenancy that covers exactly what you are attempting here.:

http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/multi-presentation-websites-for-c/

Good luck!